# Accessing the top scores from a Firebase database query, using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have managed to display users and their scores within my tableView. However, I would really like to be able to only access the top 50. Unfortunately the way I am currently storing my database means that I first observe the Users "child". and I can't use queryEnding as the data for the username is grabbed separately from the highscore and both are then added to a dictionary. Please see below.....

```
var userName = ""
var highScore = 0
var usernameHighScoreArray: [Int : String] = [:]

func retrieveUserData() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        if let dataFB = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
            for(_, value) in dataFB {
                if let scoreData = value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                    if let uname = scoreData["username"] as? String {
                        self.userName = uname
                        print("Username \(uname)")
                    }
                    if let hScore = scoreData["highScore"] as? Int {
                        self.highScore = hScore
                        print("HighScore \(hScore)")
                        self.usernameHighScoreArray[self.highScore] = self.userName
                    }
                }
            }
            self.topScoresTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my database layout...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FndV2.jpg

Is there anyway I can just pull out the 50 top highScores, at the moment the scores table is only showing a list of usernames and their scores in a list that isn't in any particular order.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Below is how the structure of my database looks via text

Users

3vPyk7EIw4eTU8hUgRzCDiGGpV23

highScore: 839
username: "Davve"

EkQWKDBuhdcghk1F6ZC0XlvDiNs2

highScore: 1476
username: "Qaz"

yDNHXJ8f7acFNdO6kOKseFPj7Zz1

highScore: 1479
username: "Ijn"

Comment: In general, please include your structure as text instead of a link or an image. It would have been a lot faster for me to answer if I could have copied and pasted that right from your question. You can get your structure from the Firebase console->Export JSON and then copy and paste it into your question. Also note there are no tables in Firebase, it's a JSON structure and it always ordered by key. It's up to you through code to determine the ordering for your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use queryLimited(toLast: x) and then insert the results at array position 0 to invert the order? Let me try this answer and see if it works for your question; assume we want the two highest scores:

Given a structure

```
Users
   uid_0
      highScore: 1171
      username: "Qaz"
   uid_1
      highScore: 1170
      username: "Trony"
   uid_2
      highScore: 672
      username: "Balls"
   uid_3
      highScore: 1172
      username: "Sam"
```

So the two high scores are Sam with 1172 and Qaz with 1171.

The idea here is the let Firebase order the scores, which will be ascending (low to high) and then pick off the last 2 which will be the two high scores.

Lets start with an class to store each name and score - we would us this as a dataSource for our tableView.

```
class ScoreClass {
    var name = ""
    var score = 0
    init(withName: String, andScore: Int) {
        self.name = withName
        self.score = andScore
    }
}
```

then an array to store the ScoreClass's in

```
var scoresArray = [ScoreClass]()
```

and then the code to query Firebase. We are ordering the results by highscore and only want the last two, which will be Sam and Qaz

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("users")
let query = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "highscore").queryLimited(toLast: 2)
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let name = dict["Name"] as! String
        let score = dict["highscore"] as! Int
        let aScore = ScoreClass(withName: name, andScore: score)
        scoresArray.insert(aScore, at: 0)
    }

    for s in scoresArray { //print them to console
        print(s.score, s.name)
    }
})
```

and the result is

```
1172 Sam
1171 Qaz
```

Note that as we iterate over the snapshot we insert them into array position 0, which means the last score read in (the highest, 1172) will be a the 'top' of the array at position 0.

Comment: Thanks for excellent reply, I have incorporated this into my VC, and it seems to run, (it prints succesfully) however I am having some difficulty now displaying the values of username and highscore from the scoresArray in my tableView.

Unsure of how to use indexPath.row with the different pairs in the array.

Comment: @rb2030 There should be a direct correlation between the row being requested to display and that same row (index) in the array. If you are using a ScoreClass like in my answer you can just get the ScorClass object from the dataSource array as in *let scoreClassObject = scoresArray[index]* and then access the two properties with *let name = scoreClassObject.name* and *let score = scoreClassObject.score*. You will probably want to make the ScoreClass obect and scoresArray class variables so your tableView delegate methods can get to them (self.scoresArray etc)

Comment: I seem to keep getting index out of range. Even when I set the results to only come back with one highScore. I shall have to look at it tomorrow I think and will update you, thanks for your help so far it is much appreciated.
        
        let cell = topScoresTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        var scoreClassObject = scoresArray[1]
        let name = scoreClassObject.name
        let score = scoreClassObject.score
        cell.usernameLabel.text = name
        cell.resultLabel.text = String(score)
        return cell

Comment: *ar scoreClassObject = scoresArray[1]* should probably be *ar scoreClassObject = scoresArray[row]*

Comment: Do you mean?.... scoreClassObject = scoresArray[indexPath.row]

Because it says that is out of range too

Comment: For some reason, after retrieving the data, func tableView numberOfRowsInSection is completely missed, it jumps straight to tableView cellForRowAt where it crashes at indexOutOfRange on the scoreClassObject = scoresArray[indexPath.row] line.

Comment: I think we would need to see how you are populating your array and then the two tableView delegate methods. It really sounds like a different question as my answer demonstrates and answers how to get the top scores based on your structure - populating a tableView with your current code may be best asked separately.

Comment: Understood, I will mark this question as correct. Please find the link below to the code I am trying to make work......

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604422/populating-an-array-of-pairs-into-a-tableview-from-firebase-to-display-only-the

Comment: Interestingly this solution only brings back the last three additions to the database, not the highest scores.

Comment: @rb2030 Nope. It brings back the last two scores, and remember they are ordered ascending with *queryOrdered(byChild: "highscore")* so the two highest will be 'at the bottom' which is why we retrieve the last two with *.queryLimited(toLast: 2)*

Comment: Ok, sorry yes, I had a typo with "highScore". All working great. Thanks again!