# Populating an array of pairs into a tableView from Firebase to display only the top 3 highest scores

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I am trying to populate my tableView with an array of pairs (one Int, one String). Unfortunately I am having some trouble understanding why it is not working as I can't seem to make the tableView populate, I receive indexOutOfRange as an error. I am using firebase as my database to retrieve the data I would like to populate. Please see below....

```
class Leaderboard: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

private let padding = 12

private var quiz: Quiz!
private let backgroundImageView = UIImageView()
private let contentView = UIView()
private let leaderboardLabel = UILabel()
private let rankLabel = UILabel()
private let userLabel = UILabel()
private let scoreLabel = UILabel()
private let tableViewCellHeight: CGFloat = 60
private let bottomButton = BottomBorderedButtons()

var scoresArray = [ScoreClass]()

var topScoresTableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    return tableView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    retrieveUserData()
    setupViews()
}

required init(quiz: Quiz) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    defer {
        self.quiz = quiz
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }

class ScoreClass {

var name = ""
var score = 0

init(withName: String, andScore: Int) {
    name = withName
    score = andScore
  }
}

let ref = Database.database().reference()

func retrieveUserData() {

    let postsRef = self.ref.child("Users")
    let query = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "highscore").queryLimited(toLast: 3)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let name = dict["username"] as! String
            let score = dict["highScore"] as! Int
            let aScore = ScoreClass(withName: name, andScore: score)
            self.scoresArray.insert(aScore, at: 0)
        }

        for s in self.scoresArray {
            print(s.score, s.name)
        }
    })
        self.topScoresTableView.reloadData()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var countarr = 0
    for s in self.scoresArray {
        countarr = s.name.count
        print(s.score, s.name)
        print(countarr)
    }
    return countarr
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = topScoresTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let scoreClassObject = scoresArray[indexPath.row]
    let name = scoreClassObject.name
    let score = scoreClassObject.score
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.usernameLabel.text = name
    cell.resultLabel.text = String(score)
    cell.rankNumberLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    print(scoresArray)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10.0
}

func setupViews() {
    view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    backgroundImageView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.addSubview(leaderboardLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(rankLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(userLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(scoreLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(topScoresTableView)
    contentView.addSubview(bottomButton)

    self.backgroundImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(topLayoutGuide.snp.bottom)
        make.leading.equalToSuperview()
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }

    self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.backgroundImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Stars.png")

    self.contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }

    contentView.backgroundColor = transluscentGrey

    self.leaderboardLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.leading.equalToSuperview()
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalTo(topScoresTableView.snp.top).offset(-50)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
    }

    leaderboardLabel.textAlignment = .center
    leaderboardLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    leaderboardLabel.textColor = .white
    leaderboardLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28.0)
    leaderboardLabel.text = "Leaderboard"
    leaderboardLabel.backgroundColor = tableViewCell

    self.rankLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(leaderboardLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10)
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(padding)
        make.height.equalTo(30)
    }

    rankLabel.textAlignment = .center
    rankLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    rankLabel.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
    rankLabel.textColor = .white
    rankLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Medium", size: 3)

    rankLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    rankLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    rankLabel.text = "Rank"

    self.userLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(leaderboardLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10)
        make.leading.equalTo(rankLabel.snp.trailing).offset(padding)
        make.height.equalTo(30)
        make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.50)
    }

    userLabel.textAlignment = .center
    userLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    userLabel.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
    userLabel.textColor = .white
    userLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Medium", size: 3)
    userLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    userLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    userLabel.text = "Username"

    self.scoreLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(leaderboardLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10)
        make.leading.equalTo(userLabel.snp.trailing).offset(padding)
        make.height.equalTo(30)
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-padding)
    }

    scoreLabel.textAlignment = .center
    scoreLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    scoreLabel.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
    scoreLabel.textColor = .white
    scoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Medium", size: 3)
    scoreLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    scoreLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    scoreLabel.text = "Score"

    self.topScoresTableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview()
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.65)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-30)
    }

    topScoresTableView.delegate = self
    topScoresTableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    topScoresTableView.dataSource = self
    topScoresTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    self.bottomButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.lessThanOrEqualTo(topScoresTableView.snp.bottom).offset(5)
        make.width.equalTo(60)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-5)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
    }
    self.bottomButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.bottomButton.backgroundColor = .yellow
}
}
```

Comment: Check your numberOfRowsInSection function. You are returning the wrong count.

Comment: Even when I amend the count to return self.scoresArray.count.  func tableView cellForRowAt doesn't get called

Comment: The *self.topScoresTableView.reloadData()* is in the wrong place. Firebase is asychronous and that will be called way before the data is read in the closure. You need to call the tableView.reloadData() in the closure so it executes after the data is read in. Right after the for s in self.scoresArray loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's decompose this into it's parts

The ScoreClass objects which are populated from Firebase and hold the name and score

```
class ScoreClass {
   var name = ""
   var score = 0
   init(withName: String, andScore: Int) {
      name = withName
      score = andScore
   }
}
```

The array to hold the ScoreClass objects that is used as the dataSource for tableView

```
var scoresArray = [ScoreClass]()
```

The code to read Firebase and fill the array

```
func getScoresAndNamesFromFirebaseAndStuffIntoArray() {
    let postsRef = self.ref.child("Users")
    let query = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "highscore").queryLimited(toLast: 3)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let name = dict["username"] as! String
            let score = dict["highScore"] as! Int
            let aScore = ScoreClass(withName: name, andScore: score)
            self.scoresArray.insert(aScore, at: 0)
        }
        self.topScoresTableView.reloadData()
    })     
}
```

and then the tableView delegate methods. There are three functions to handle the tableView. This assumes your text cell in the tableView has an identifier of NameScoreCell

```
let textCellIdentifier = "NameScoreCell"

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return scoresArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    let scoreObject = scoresArray[row]
    let score = scoreObject.score
    let name = scoreObject.name
    cell.nameLabel?.text = name
    cell.scoreLabel?.text = score

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return self.scoresArray.count
}
```

Comment: But when I do this func tableView cellForRowAt doesn't get called at all. So nothing displays in the tableView.

Comment: Where is setupViews()? Where is the tableView added to the view? Where is the tableView delegate and datasource set? I think there are a few steps missing.

Comment: Sorry didn't put them in as I thought it would be a bit too long. I have added them to the question.

Comment: Ok. Jay's answer re when to call reloadData() combined with this should see you right.